# Python: How do i determine the angle that makes the ball travel the furthest when throwing?

Tags: python, numpy

Edit:
I  realized now that 180 degrees is wrong, it should have been from 0-90 degrees, so edited that. sorry.

First time asking a question on Stackoverflow so I'm so sorry if I've done anything wrong.

Usually I try to google my way to my answers but this time I have absolutely zero clue, and the only place where it looks like I could find a similar task was on wired, but the links does not work unfortunately.

My problem:
I'm attempting to show in a graph what angle is the best angle to throw at in order to make the ball travel the furthest.
So far I have been able to draw all possible outcomes when thrown at any angle between 0 and 90. However this looks really messy, how can I make it so that the furthest distance on the x axis is "highlighted".

I do know that 45 degrees is the best angle, and I guess I could just hardcode it in, but is there another (simple) way to show it?

See the link further down for the results i get with my current code.

My code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x0 = 0.0 # Startposition on x-axis
y0 = 0.0 # Startposition on y-axis
v0 = 10.0 # Startvelocity
g = 9.81 # Gravity
dt = 0.01 # Time resolution (number of seconds per time step)
N = 200 # Amount of time steps
th0 = 0.0 # The angle the ball is thrown at

# Calculations
x = np.zeros((1, N))
y = np.zeros((1, N))

# I begin with this as i want to test all angles between 0 (horizontal) and up to 90(straight up)
for th0 in range(90):   
    for k in range(N):
        x[0,k] = x0 + v0*np.cos(th0*np.pi/180.0)*dt*k # motion equation on x-axis. No acceleration
        y[0,k] = y0 + v0*np.sin(th0*np.pi/180.0)*dt*k - 0.5*g*(dt*k)*(dt*k) # motion equation on y-axis. gravity acceleration.
    plt.plot(x[0,:], y[0,:])
    plt.plot([0,12],[0,0])
    th0=th0+1
plt.grid()
plt.axis([0, 12, 0, 12])
plt.show()
```

As u can see in the image linked below, everything is kinda messy, i wish i could highlight the line at which the ball travels the furthest and the angle it is thrown at.
[image: here]

Again sorry if my english is terrible or if ive done anything else the wrong way.
I speed translated the code, so some of the comments may be a bit weird.

Edit2:
I want it to look kind of like the picture below, just without the hardcoding, however i might have a solution, just due to my exams i dont have time to look more at it atm. If anyone ever comes across this and is wondering about the same let me know. If not i guess ill just close this (if thats even possible).

[image: this]

Answer (score 2):

You can calculate the best angle analytically:

```
y = -g/2*t**2 + v*sin(theta)*t

# Require y == 0 for t > 0:
t = 2*v/g * sin(theta)
x = v*cos(theta) * 2*v/g*sin(theta)

# Compute the derivative of 'x' with respect to 'theta':
xp = 2*v**2/g * (cos(theta)**2 - sin(theta)**2)

# Require xp == 0 to find the maximum.
# From this follows that `cos(theta)**2 = sin(theta)**2`.
theta = pi/4
```

So the result is indeed `pi/4` or 45 degrees. You can use this information to color your plot:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

v, g = 10, 9.81

def compute_xy(theta):
    t_max = 2*v/g * np.sin(theta)
    t = np.linspace(0, t_max, 100)
    x = v * np.cos(theta) * t
    y = -g/2 * t**2 + v*np.sin(theta)*t
    return x, y

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set(xlabel='x [m]', ylabel='y [m]')

for theta in np.linspace(0, np.pi/2, 100):
    ax.plot(*compute_xy(theta), '-', color='#1f77b4', lw=0.7, alpha=0.4)

# Best trajectory:
ax.plot(*compute_xy(np.pi/4), '-', color='#ff7f0e', lw=2, label='Optimal')
ax.legend()

plt.show()
```

[image: Example plot showing trajectories]

Alternatively you can precompute all trajectories and then find the one with the largest x-range:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

v, g = 10, 9.81

def compute_xy(theta):
    t_max = 2*v/g * np.sin(theta)
    t = np.linspace(0, t_max, 100)
    x = v * np.cos(theta) * t
    y = -g/2 * t**2 + v*np.sin(theta)*t
    return x, y

thetas = np.linspace(0, np.pi/2, 100)
trajectories = np.stack([compute_xy(t) for t in thetas])
best_index = np.argmax(trajectories[:, 0, -1])
print(f'Best angle: {thetas[best_index]/np.pi:.2f} [pi]')

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set(xlabel='x [m]', ylabel='y [m]')
ax.plot(*trajectories.reshape(-1, len(thetas)), '-', color='#1f77b4', lw=0.7, alpha=0.4)
ax.plot(*trajectories[best_index], '-', color='#ff7f0e', lw=2, label='Optimal')
ax.legend()

plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you very much! i will have to try this out tomorrow! Does look exactly like what i wanted! :)